# Generating client library of app engine project takes too long

Tags: android, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, google-cloud-messaging, gae-eclipse-plugin

I am developing app engine connected android application. For that i have created entity in app engine application and then i am generating endpoint classes of that. After that when i Generate Client Library For Android app, it takes too much time in generating that. I don't know why this happens. Is there any problem with eclipse or app engine?

Comment: How much time is too much?  How long should it take?  Is your computer ever slow with anything else?

Comment: i have 7 entity endpoint classes and it takes around 30 minutes to generate client, which is quite long. My computer doesn't slow with anything else.

Comment: Yes, such a long time seems wrong.  I have no answer, but the two areas I would be suspicious of are the Eclipse installation and the content of your project.  If you could temporarily try installing an extra copy of Eclipse and create a very simple Endpoint project, it may give insights into what is wrong.

Comment: This is definitely out of range of expected time. Have you tried generating the same from the command line ?

Comment: @Romin no i haven't tried from command line.